# How can I calculate a CRC-32 on an NSData object in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, crc32

I have tried using the crc32( ) function in zlib, but it fails to link because _crc32 is an undefined symbol for architecture arm64.

Comment: Google, there are many CRC-32 Objective-C solutions easily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `_crc32` is undefined, then you most likely forgot to add *libz.dylib* to the linked frameworks and libraries. It should definitely be available.

You add it by clicking on the project in the *Project navigator*, selecting the target and the tab *General* and then clicking on the plus sign at the very bottom. Then type "libz", select *libz.dylib* and click *Add*.